# Not able to access Isilon Server

Tags: c#, isilon

I am trying to connect Isilon server using the below code. But I am getting 400 Bad Request as a response. Can you help me with this?

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var IsilonServerAddress = "http://192.168.45.151:8080";
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(IsilonServerAddress + "/namespace/ ");
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("root" + ":" + "root")));
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
```

The Server should return me the proper response as output.

Answer (score 0):

The response suggests you are feeding something Isilon does not like (syntax etc).

1. Check if WebUI services are running:

isilon-1# isi services -a isi_webui

Most likely it is running since you are getting *some* response, but would not hurt to check for sanity.

2. use curl to verify the OneFS API is working properly. Use the curl command with "root" user credentials.

For example list SMB shares:

```
isilon-1# curl -vk -u "root" -H 'Content-type:application/json' -X GET 'https://<Isilon_IP>:8080/platform/1/protocols/smb/shares'
```

For more information check EMC KBA# 304504:
**How to use the curl command to verify the OneFS API is working properly in OneFS 7.0 and later**
http://support.emc.com/kb/304504

Also see the following doc:

**Dell EMC Isilon OneFS Version 8.1.2 API Reference**
https://support.emc.com/docu90414_Isilon-OneFS-8.1.2-API-Reference-Guide.pdf?language=en_US